# Why being the discriminant $D<0$ guarantees that there is a saddle point in some direction?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm studying multi-variable calculus, and stopped at this theorem:

[image]

I'm wondering why being the discriminant $D<0$ guarantees that there is a saddle point in some direction ?

Answer (score 1):

If $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ have the same sign, then $D$ can still be positive or negative.

As an example, take $f(x,y) = \pm(x^2 + y^2) + 2 \alpha xy$ where $|\alpha| > 1$.

Comment: I plotted your example and found that although both second derivative in x and y directions are positive, a saddle point still exists!

Comment: So, the question may be edited to: Why being the discriminant $D<0$ guarantees that there is a saddle point in some direction?

Comment: I found the answer after several pages in the textbook :) thanks